# Plotting Time Series graphs in R

Tags: r, plot, timeserieschart

I need to plot a time series in R. But having a tough time to figure out how to work with the formats.

```
dates <- c(20060901, 20060905, 20060906, 20060907, 20060908, 20060911)
values <- c(33.6, 32.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 28.4)
```

Need to convert the dates in proper Format E.g: 20060901 to Sep-01-2006 and so on

**My approach so far:**

```
dates = as.Date(dates, "%Y%m%d")
plot(dates , values)
```

However, I get the following error :

```
Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: Now that you updated your question after I posted my answer, try to at least copy all the relevant parts.  Hint: `as.character()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to read some basic docs to learn more about basic types, but here is a worked example using your data:

```
R> data <- data.frame(dates=as.Date(as.character(c(20060901,20060905,20060906, 
+                                                  20060907,20060908,20060911)), 
+                                   "%Y%m%d"), 
+                     values=c(33.6, 32.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 28.4))
R> data
       dates values
1 2006-09-01   33.6
2 2006-09-05   32.0
3 2006-09-06   30.0
4 2006-09-07   30.0
5 2006-09-08   30.0
6 2006-09-11   28.4
R> class(data[,1])
[1] "Date"
R> plot(data)
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Based on the experience of the OP, they may also need info on how to make this a line plot instead of points: `plot(data, type="l")`; otherwise, I'm not sure why they have not accepted your answer yet!